# Old commits and new commits are on separate repositories, how to concatenate them?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm facing the following problem.

I wanted to fork an old software hosted on SourceForge. I did it the simple way, I've just downloaded the latest revision of the code and added the files to a git repo.

Therefore, the commit #987 is commit #1 on my git repo.
I then started working on it.

Then, I've realised it would be better to have kept a record of the old commits previous developers made on SourceForge.

I've managed to convert their repo to git.

So, to illustrate this, I have now two repositories.
Repo A is the first one I've made, which contains only my commits, but not the history of the previous commits made by the developers.
Repo B is a the svn to git conversion of the SourceForge repo.

I know I can transfer commits from repo A to repo B because A contains newer commits.
But I would like to transfer older commits from repo B to repo A.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIU, in the end, you want a repo with all the commits, both old and new ones.

The simplest for me would be to:

- start with a repo containing the old commits
- add a remote in this old repo, pointing at a repo with the new commits, and fetch
- cherry-pick the new commits on your `master` branch which contains the old commits

so it would basically looks like

```
cd old_repo
git remote add new ../new_repo
git fetch --all
# at this point we have two streams of commits with no common ancestor

#let's say you have 20 new commits, in a single branch
git cherry-pick new/master~20
git cherry-pick new/master~19
...
git cherry-pick new/master~1
git cherry-pick new/master
```